# Insect identification, Bangalore India

Tags: species-identification, species

Can anyone identify this insect? It was sitting on my refrigerator.

Size: approximately 1 cm height, 1 inch across

My location: Bangalore, India

[image]

Comment: Some sort of [Plume Moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterophoridae), but I can't tell what kind specifically.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moths_of_India_(Pterophoridae) ... one of those then, pick your favourite

Answer (score 4):

So i did some more research and found some canon photos of two moth species both found in india and super similar to this

- both of them have brown spots around them
- both of them are found in india
   **So it was hard for me to eliminate one of them** 
  here are both the insects
  ***Sphenarches Anisodactylus***
  [image: similar right]

***Sphenarches caffer***
[image: This too is similar]
So now its up to you to decide which one it is???

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer a bit - how you determined this, what rules out other genera, etc? Also, please include a photo/image in the actual answer rather than a link.

Comment: Those are actually the photos

Comment: To me they just appear as hyperlinks. If the photos are showing when you look at the answer, I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: I mean not exactly photos but it was sure a photo when i copied the link and inserted link for the image insertion option

Comment: Done I inserted the photos

Comment: My pleasure to help people